# Can I provide a customized name for folders pinned to the windows explorer taskbar icon context menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

When I right click on the windows explorer icon on the taskbar I get a list of folders, some pinned that I always want and some frequent.  I want some pinned ones to be folders with the same name in different locations eg:

c:\users\username\project\bin
c:\users\username\project2\bin
c:\users\username\project3\bin

but they just use the folder name for to identify themselves in the context menu so they all appear as 'bin'

Can I customise this name in any way so I can call them Proj1 bin, proj2 bin etc etc?

Answer (score 2):

The feature (when you right-click the Task Bar icon) is called a Jump List. 
For some reason, Windows doesn't cooperate with simple solutions to this (like just right-clicking and renaming the pinned item).

You can work around this by pinning a renamed shortcut to the Jump List.

1. Before you begin, **unpin the folder** you want to rename.  If it appears in the frequent list when you right-click, you'll also need to right-click it **and remove it from the frequent list**.
2. Create a shortcut to the folder you want to pin. An easy way is to right-click and drag the folder to your Desktop (or another location) and select "Create shortcuts here."
3. Rename the shortcut as you'd like it to appear on the Jump List.
4. Drag and drop the shortcut onto the Explorer icon on the Task Bar (unlike other shortcuts, folder shortcuts must be dropped directly onto Explorer and not just a blank spot on the Task Bar).

The folder should now be pinned with the shortcut name. You can delete the shortcut once you've pinned the folder, it was just a middle-man.

This works on Windows 7, 8, and 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

The free application [Jumplist-Launcher](http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/) may give you the flexibility you require
(not using Windows 7, I haven't tried it on Explorer or at all.)